# Clickable hyperlink Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I've tried this code to create a clickable hyperlink in Shiny Dashboard, but the image doesn't show up for some reason (I get a question mark kind of an icon, but it's hyperlinked)

```
`dashboardBody(

tabItems(
tabItem("icratio",
        fluidRow(
          a(img(src="image.png"), href="https://google.com")

        )
)
 )
)`
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is image.png in the \www folder, or the same folder as the code?

Comment: Have it in just the app folder. Do we need to create a www folder?

Comment: Yes - create a folder called www in the folder with your app, and then put the image file in that. That should fix the problem, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Putting **tags$a** should work.

```
tabItem("icratio",
    fluidRow(
      tags$a(img(src="image.png"), href="https://google.com")
    )
)
```